# Cops: The Hidden OEIS Substring

Tags: code-challenge, sequence, integer, cops-and-robbers

This is a Cops and Robbers challenge. This is the cop's thread. The [robber's thread is here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/188143/31716).

As a cop, you must pick any sequence from the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/), and write a program **p** that prints the first integer from that sequence. You must also find some string **s**. If you insert **s** somewhere into **p**, this program must print the second integer from the sequence. If you insert **s + s** into the same location in **p**, this program must print the third integer from the sequence. **s + s + s** in the same location will print the fourth, and so on and so forth. Here's an example:

> ## Python 3, sequence [A000027](https://oeis.org/A000027)
>
> ```
> print(1)
> ```
>
> The hidden string is **two bytes**.

The string is `+1`, because the program `print(1+1)` will print the second integer in A000027, the program `print(1+1+1)` will print the third integer, etc.

Cops must reveal the sequence, the original program **p**, and the length of the hidden string **s**. Robbers crack a submission by finding any string *up to* that length and the location to insert it to create the sequence. The string does not need to match the intended solution to be a valid crack, nor does the location it's inserted at.

### Rules

- Your solution must work for any number in the sequence, or at least until a reasonable limit where it fails do to memory restrictions, integer/stack overflow, etc.
- The winning robber is the user who cracks the most submissions, with the tiebreaker being who reached that number of cracks first.
- The winning cop is the cop with the shortest string **s** that isn't cracked. Tiebreaker is the shortest **p**. If there are no uncracked submissions, the cop who had a solution uncracked for longest wins.
- To be declared safe, your solution must stay uncracked for 1 week and then have the hidden string (and location to insert it) revealed.
- **s** may not be nested, it must concatenated end to end. For example, if **s** was `10`, each iteration would go `10, 1010, 101010, 10101010...` rather than `10, 1100, 111000, 11110000...`
- It is acceptable to start on the second term of the sequence rather than the first.
- If your sequence has a finite number of terms, going past the last term is allowed to result in undefined behavior.
- All cryptographic solutions (for example, checking the hash of the substring) are banned.
- If **s** contains any non-ASCII characters, you must also specify the encoding being used.

Comment: For anyone attempting to find a good sequence, the OEIS has a [webcam](http://oeis.org/webcam) that selects random sequences.

Comment: If I claim "the hidden string has length 10 or less", my answer is not cracked, and my hidden string actually has length 8, what is my score? Or is it simply not allowed to claim a larger length than your actual length?

Comment: @LuisMendo I would probably say that claiming a larger length than your actual length is not allowed. Is there any reason you'd want to? That would probably just make it easier for robbers.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Probably no reason, other than cause confusion. But I agree it's better not to allow that. (The claimed length in my answer exactly corresponds to my hidden string)

Answer (score 21):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), sequence [A005206](http://oeis.org/A005206). [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188143/robbers-the-hidden-oeis-substring/188407#188407) by [SamYonnou](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12324/samyonnou)

```
voOdoO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyzfPyXf//9/AA)

The hidden string has **8 bytes**.

Comment: voodoo??? I'm convinced MATL is black magic now

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188407/12324)

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), sequence [A138147](https://oeis.org/A138147) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188212/20260))

```python
print 10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EwdDg/38A)

The hidden string is **7 bytes**. The sequence goes:

```python
10, 1100, 111000, 11110000, 1111100000, ...
```

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188212/1683)

Comment: Since the challenge specifies that any string _up to_ the given length can be used to crack, this can also be done relatively trivially with just a 2 byte string

Comment: @Theo how? As I understand it, the string needs to be inserted repeatedly end to end, not nested

Comment: @DreamConspiracy oh you're probably right, I took "If you insert s into the same location in p" to mean that you could nest them.

Answer (score 7):

### [Keg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg), sequence [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045)

```
0.
```

The hidden string is ≤*6 bytes*(in order to conform the updated cracking rules)

Comment: Correct, the rules say *any string up to that length*.

Comment: No TIO for Keg :-(

Comment: Assuming no unicode characters are used, there is no such string of length ≤3. (I looped over all of them.) I used [master^](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg/commit/329a0cb23c6a90e97eaed4be4ee27925dcea54a5), since [master](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg/commit/34d4d8789037dd6aadd091a959abdc1c1b8eec46) crashes on your initial program. So you either need to explain how to run your interpreter correctly, or fix it. :P

Comment: If I should not just revert the last commit (as I did), what version should I revert to?

Comment: My program was invalid. I rewrote my program.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188218/6689)

Comment: @LuisMendo not yet at least

Comment: @tomsmeding what exactly do you mean by crashing?

Comment: @Jono2906 You can [ask Dennis](https://talk.tryitonline.net) to include it. But better wait a few days, based on the comments in the chat room

Comment: @Jono2906 `$ python3 Keg.py examples/cat.keg` produces `IndexError: list index out of range`; before commit 34d4d87, the interpreter seemed to work.

Comment: @tomsmeding [fixed](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg/commit/f26a9ef0adf996bb2c368196a6fd80d60f90f353).

Answer (score 5):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188156/56656)

## <s>[Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), sequence [A000290](http://oeis.org/A000290) (Square numbers)</s>

```
((()))({}<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fQ0NDU1NTo7rWxk7z/38A)

The hidden string is **6 bytes**.

#### Fun fact:

I "discovered" this property while playing [this brain-flak based game](https://gitlab.com/e-neighborhood-watch/cal_final).  The hidden string was a randomly generated item that I discovered was very useful.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188156/25180)

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyret](https://code.pyret.org/), sequence [A083420](https://oeis.org/A083420), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188143/robbers-the-hidden-oeis-substring/188249#188249)

```
fold({(b,e):(2 * b) + 1},1,[list: ])
```

The hidden string has **4 bytes** or fewer.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188249/73884) You're new here; welcome to Code Golf SE! How are you liking it so far?

Comment: Nice! Thanks, I’m learning as I go!

Answer (score 5):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), sequence [A000290](http://oeis.org/A000290). Cracked by [Cows quack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188408/41805)

```
é*Ø.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///BKrcMz9P7/BwA)

The hidden string is **5 bytes**.

Comment: This doesn't print the first term of the sequence A000290 which is 0...

Comment: @ExpiredData Hmm. I could easily edit my answer to start at 0 without affecting the byte count, but there are several other answers that start on the second term too. I don't really want to invalidate those

Comment: [Cracked in 4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188408/41805)

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8+, sequence [A010686](https://oeis.org/A010686) ([cracked by xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188268/84303))

Lambda function.

```java
()->System.out.println(1);
```

The hidden string is ≤ 5 bytes

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188268/20260)

Comment: That is indeed one of the 2 possible strings I came up with @xnor. The other was `^2<<1` but that's the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

### [Python 3](https://www.python.org), sequence [A096582](https://oeis.org/A096582)

This is really trivial, as I haven't tried Cops and Robbers challenges before.

```
print(100)
```

The hidden string is *3 bytes.*

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188153/67312)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), sequence [A014092](http://oeis.org/A014092) - ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188143/robbers-the-hidden-oeis-substring/188311#188311))

```python
from sympy import isprime, primerange
from itertools import count
r=1
print(r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nco7CoAwDADQvafIqOAizh5GpGrAfEjjkNNHKTi95Wn4JbxkHiYELUgDkFTMAZsaUp2gYxuftfSFXs1F7vbPXR72Yutcvso@2Jj5Ag)

The hidden sequence is **82 bytes**.

My intended code (which doesn't rely on the Goldbach Conjecture) was:

```python
i=(n for n in count(2)if all(not isprime(n-x) for x in primerange(1,n)))
r=next(i)
#
```

**Cracked** by [NieDzejkob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55934/niedzejkob), who uses the [Goldbach Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) to solve it in a [magical 42](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/42) characters. Great job!

Comment: Did you assume the Goldbach conjecture?

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188311/55934)

Answer (score 4):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), [A000042](http://oeis.org/A000042) - ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188346/55934))

```forth
1 .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//Gyro/f8PAA)

The hidden sequence is **5 bytes**, and it can easily handle hundreds of terms.

A one-byte solution that breaks due to integer overflow is also possible. In fact, I'd say it is embarrassingly trivial. While the challenge text, under some interpretations, might allow you to call that a crack, I urge you not to.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188346/73884) I liked this one.

Answer (score 3):

### [Desktop Calculator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), sequence [A006125](https://oeis.org/A006125)

```
1n
```

The hidden string *≤ 12 bytes*.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188219/25180)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), sequence [A000984](https://oeis.org/A000984) (central binomial coefficients)

```
(())({{}}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fQ0NTU6O6ura2ulbz/38A)

The hidden string has **36 bytes** or fewer.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188264/56656).

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), [A268575](http://oeis.org/A268575)

```python
from itertools import product
S,F,D=lambda*x:tuple(map(sum,zip(*x))),lambda f,s:(v for x in s for v in f(x)),lambda s:{(c-48>>4,c&15)for c in map(ord,s)}
W=D("6@AQUVW")
print(len(W))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcy7CsIwGEDhvU8ROsifEgexihRaFIq7iHauaYOB3EjSEhWfPRId3M7wcczD37Vax8isloj70XqthUNcGm09MlYPE/XZmRxJW4te3oa@CJWfjBhB9gbcJMmTGygCxpj8AGLEVTAjpi0KiCvkvjmnZBD@zlUvoMty1zQloYvVBidGE0trbQfi8Dvr6hby7f5wuly7HGfGcuVBjAo6jGP8AA)

The hidden sequence is **102 bytes.**

Comment: [Cracked by Liresol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188433/76162)

Comment: @Liresol has [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188143/robbers-the-hidden-oeis-substring/188433#188433) your answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [AsciiDots](https://github.com/aaronduino/asciidots), 36 bytes, [A019523](http://oeis.org/A019523)

```
/>1#*$_#\
*^-{+})./
|/\/\/\
\/\/\/\&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxOzsxMyS8p/v9f385QWUslXjmGSytOt1q7VlNPn6tGPwYEuWIgtNr//wA)

The hidden string has **12 bytes**.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188414/69059)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), sequence [A083318](http://oeis.org/A083318) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188546/20260))

```hs
f=length[2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P802JzUvvSQj2ij2f25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQtr/f8lpOYnpxf91kwsKAA)

The hidden string is **5 bytes**. The sequence goes:

```hs
1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 33, 65, 129, 257, 513, ...
```

Comment: Nice one! [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188546/34531)

Answer (score 2):

## [VDM-SL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/overturetool/documentation/master/documentation/VDM10LangMan/VDM10_lang_man.pdf), sequence [A000312](https://oeis.org/A000312)

```cs
let m={1|->{0}}in hd reverse[x**x|x in set m(1)&x<card m(1)]
```

The hidden string has **33 bytes** or fewer

Comment: That VDM-SL link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @nichartley it's a link to the language manual as a PDF.. so maybe you're viewing it on something that can't view PDFs

Comment: [This](https://github.com/overturetool/documentation/blob/editing/documentation/VDM10LangMan/VDM10_lang_man.pdf) works.

Comment: This doesn't quite seem to be a full program... and I haven't actually figured out how to turn it into one yet. Obviously it's assigning a lambda to `m`, but I can't tell how to actually call it

Comment: ...except it's not, because the `in` is already there, so it's not even a function, just an expression? A REPL snippet? At least I've figured out how to run it...

Comment: @unrelatedstring yes it's an expression, you could also run it by having a function that takes no parameters and returns a `seq of nat`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188483/85334)

Comment: ...unless this is supposed to print the first `n` numbers in the sequence for `n` string repetitions? That's not my understanding of the rules

Comment: I don't mind at all (and already deleted my robbers post)

Comment: @UnrelatedString I've added a binding to the set comprehension which should force you to use the 35 byte plan I initially had, also the hd reverse should make it pop the last element. I noticed 2 bytes I could golf from the string so it's now 33. GL if you're still trying!

Comment: That should be fun, thanks

Comment: I've found a disappointingly trivial 13-byte crack, but I think I'll at least try to find the intended solution before posting it.

Comment: Now I'm trying to use composition, but 1) it's killing Overture because maps are supposed to be finite and 2) the string I've arrived at (which ended up just causing an `internal error`) is way longer than 33. So now I'm really getting curious as to why `m` is a map

Comment: 13 bytes :o I'm not very good at this challenge then haha. In VDM you can define consecutive let statements for the same variable and reference the previous one my solution used that if that clue helps. M is a map just to make things more confusing @unrelatedstring

Comment: The 13 bytes are `let x=x+1 in `, bypassing the generate-first-n-terms yet again. I actually avoided doing that to `m`, under the assumption that you had not considered that possibility. I'll [post the trivial crack now](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188483/85334), but I'll keep working on the intended solution, because the closest I've gotten to it is currently at 43 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188245/73884)

## <s>[cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), sequence [A003617](https://oeis.org/A003617)</s>

```
=1#2:pZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/39ZQ2ciqIOr/fwA)

The hidden string is **1 byte**.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188245/73884)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), sequence [A000578](http://oeis.org/A000578) (Cube numbers)

```
((())<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fQ0NDU9PGTvP/fwA)

The hidden string is **16 bytes**

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188248/71256)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java 8+](http://jdk.java.net/), 1044 bytes, sequence [A008008](https://oeis.org/A008008) (Safe)

```java
class c{long[]u={1,4,11,21,35,52,74,102,136,172,212,257,306,354,400,445,488,529,563,587,595,592,584,575,558,530,482,421,354,292,232,164,85,0,-85,-164,-232,-292,-354,-421,-482,-530,-558,-575,-584,-592,-595,-587,-563,-529,-488,-445,-400,-354,-306,-257,-212,-172,-136,-102,-74,-52,-35,-21,-11,-4,-1},v={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},w={1,0,0,-1,5};long d=1,e=1;void f(long a,long b){long[]U=u,V=v,W,X;while(a-->0){U=g(U);w=h(v,w);}W=h(v,U);while(b-->0){V=g(V);v=h(v,v);}X=h(V,u);if(w[0]!=v[0]){int i,j,k=0;u=new long[i=(i=W.length)>(j=X.length)?i:j];for(;k<i;k++)u[k]=(k<i?W[k]:0)-(k<j?X[k]:0);d*=e++;}}long[]g(long[]y){int s=y.length,i=1;long[]Y=new long[s-1];for(;i<s;){Y[i-1]=y[i]*i++;}return Y;}long[]h(long[]x,long[]y){int q=x.length,r=y.length,i=0,j;long[]z=new long[q+r-1];for(;i<q;i++)if(x[i]!=0)for(j=0;j<r;)z[i+j]+=x[i]*y[j++];return z;}c(){f(3,0);System.out.println(u[0]/d);}public static void main(String[]args){new c();}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLbUqNAEP0VfGOk2@WaRMfRj7DMpSgeMCHJkEiUW4wU357tBlxjrUXNTN/mnNM9pHEdY7ranc/LfVwUxrLZH7JNGFWqccAHxwHXAS@AwIUxubYLjjcCZ@xSnFYwBs8eUYEPvm2D7wfgTyZUfQvByINgMobglm7fumT7EIzJDijvUe3EBb8D98GlvOsR9siHSQA2IO3IHnIYOY9ciHwD@SoyBjIYMioyPDIPMiEyM7IEZC3IopDVIcvsoVg4cgfIrSD3hNwccpc4ZriOlfMUZF46WqhVY8PvHzo/tv9Sl@vru4z9fut3wH/3WzjyYw3lQSv5BY2VciBRjqwPemWszS4WQ3e8iOGRn1UFU1XDDObyuNX7xIwRH2zRPKuN@SzkUW3NGo5CtrPO4lBX9tKXTalsKmTdJWsqm5M1hUpIvTaPoR1dqZp20eisNDSksFO2rFSWHI1OgFamVrObfZJtyq14MFM1/3Ie9V0ayfUhN@XuXsudZYkq3EXKJO9xRtadLZCc9HHeO3J1rRLLkm3b97Yx@/PUsxfqNECDpqn0ucW3lAKdgU7fF1I0i1BTRJ1CHV1rhs2TssozYyEH/O2A/wE/eN7VxxdPfklpQzqQfn6Tvlv5Be27JCJBk/sg0itlC46nNLH0PpfiM9RWGlmKk9enMLWsSA6aPmW7NEWzNj2gOTydijJ5vTlU5c1bTpL2mVnRI/xZ0fu8VS97vTSKMi7p6H6N11hn5lNJlaQtzjeFaFgfAdIoz@e/)

Can be solved using a hidden string of size **12**. Can definitely be golfed more, but there is no way this is actually winning. I just wanted to contribute out of respect for the number 8008.

Note: before anyone complains that the sequence is hard-coded, I've tested this up to the first term that diverges from the hard-coding (13th term = 307) and it gets it correctly albeit slowly. This is also why it's using `long` instead of `int`, otherwise it overflows before that term.

**Update (Jul 12 2019)**: updated to be a bit more performant. Computes the 13th term in 30 seconds on my computer now instead of 5 minutes.

**Update (Jul 17 2019)**: fixed bugs in for loop bounds for the `g` function, and array length bounds in the bottom of the `f` function. These bugs should have eventually caused problems, but not early enough to get caught by just checking the output. In either case, since the presence of these bugs 5 days into the game might have confused some people enough into being unable to solve this puzzle, I am totally fine with extending the "safe" deadline until July 24th for this submission.

**Update (Jul 18 2019)**: After some testing I have confirmed that overflows start after the 4th term in the sequence and start affecting the validity of the output after the 19th term. Also in the program as it is written here, each consecutive term takes roughly 5 times longer than the previous to compute. The 15th term takes about 14 minutes on my computer. So actually computing the 19th term using the program as written would take over 6 days.

Also, here is the code with sane spacing/indentation so it is a bit easier to read if people don't have an IDE with auto-formatting on hand.

```java
class c {

  long[] u = {1, 4, 11, 21, 35, 52, 74, 102, 136, 172, 212, 257, 306, 354, 400, 445, 488, 529, 563, 587, 595, 592, 584,
      575, 558, 530, 482, 421, 354, 292, 232, 164, 85, 0, -85, -164, -232, -292, -354, -421, -482, -530, -558, -575,
      -584, -592, -595, -587, -563, -529, -488, -445, -400, -354, -306, -257, -212, -172, -136, -102, -74, -52, -35,
      -21, -11, -4, -1},
      v = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
          0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
      w = {1, 0, 0, -1, 5};

  long d = 1, e = 1;

  void f(long a, long b) {
    long[] U = u, V = v, W, X;
    while (a-- > 0) {
      U = g(U);
      w = h(v, w);
    }
    W = h(v, U);
    while (b-- > 0) {
      V = g(V);
      v = h(v, v);
    }
    X = h(V, u);
    if (w[0] != v[0]) {
      int i, j, k = 0;
      u = new long[i = (i = W.length) > (j = X.length) ? i : j];
      for (; k < i; k++)
        u[k] = (k < i ? W[k] : 0) - (k < j ? X[k] : 0);
      d *= e++;
    }
  }

  long[] g(long[] y) {
    int s = y.length, i = 1;
    long[] Y = new long[s - 1];
    for (; i < s;) {
      Y[i - 1] = y[i] * i++;
    }
    return Y;
  }

  long[] h(long[] x, long[] y) {
    int q = x.length, r = y.length, i = 0, j;
    long[] z = new long[q + r - 1];
    for (; i < q; i++)
      if (x[i] != 0)
        for (j = 0; j < r;)
          z[i + j] += x[i] * y[j++];
    return z;
  }

  c() {
    f(3, 0);
    System.out.println(u[0] / d);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new c();
  }
}
```

## Solution

> `f(1,v[0]=1);` right before the `System.out.println`
>  The program works by computing the n'th Taylor expansion coefficient at 0. Where the original function is a quotient of polynomials, represented by `u` and `v` which I got from [here](https://oeis.org/A008000/a008000_1.pdf), except that in the linked document the denominator is not multiplied out, and nowhere do they say that you have to compute the Taylor series, I stumbled on that by accident and then confirmed via another source.
>  The calculation is done via repeated application of the quotient rule for derivatives.
>  The incorrect first term of `v`, the entire array `w` and a few other things like the function `f` having any arguments are thrown in to mess with people.

Comment: I guess your submission is the first uncracked one!

Comment: Added a solution

Comment: You should probably also edit the header to say that it's safe

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), sequence [A000796](https://oeis.org/A000796). [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188143/robbers-the-hidden-oeis-substring/188314#188314) by [SamYonnou](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12324/samyonnou)

```
'pi'td1_&:_1)Y$J)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X70gU70kxTBezSreUDNSxUvz/38A)

The hidden string has **3 bytes**.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188314/12324)

Answer (score 2):

## [Unefunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), sequence [A000108](http://oeis.org/A000108)

```
1.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K81LTSvNS0/VtbTQLagEM///N9Rz@P8fAA)

The hidden sequence is **19 bytes**.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188352/73884)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://haskell.org), sequence [A014675](https://oeis.org/A014675), [cracked by nimi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188353/73884)

```
main=print$uncurry(!!)([2],0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzr0SlNC@5tKioUkNRUVMj2ihWx0Dz/38A)

The hidden sequence is **35 bytes**.

Here's my intended solution:

> ```
>  main=print$uncurry(!!)$((l:n)->(l>>=flip take[2,1],n+1))([2],0)
>                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Comment: [My guess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188353/34531).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), [A008574](https://oeis.org/A008574), [cracked by xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188375/44718)

```python
print(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew1Dz/38A)

Insert 4 bytes to complete A008574. A008574: a(0)=1, thereafter a(n) = 4n.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188375/20260)

Comment: @xnor so fast... T_T

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, [A000045 (Fibonacci)](https://oeis.org/A000045) -- [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188505/73884)

```
f = head [0, 1]
```

I've got a solution with a whopping 23 bytes. I don't expect this to be safe for long, but it was super fun to come up with.

Solution:

> I thought Haskell would be a fun language to try this challenge with -- the natural thing is to do to end up adding a function call every time, but if the sequence can't be written recursively in terms of the last term only, you run into some trickiness with Haskell's strictness and function application.
>  Khuldraeseth na'Barya found a super clever way to do this with an applicative functor. I did something much less brilliant, using where-hacking:
>
> `f = head [b,a+b]where[a,b]=[0,1]
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`
>
>  (This is actually 18 bytes. My less-golfed 23 byte version, where I'd totally forgot about pattern matching, used `[last a,sum a]where a=` instead.)

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188505/73884) Welcome back!

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes ([Brachylog SBCS](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/wiki/Code-page)), [A114018](https://oeis.org/A114018) ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188485/85334))

```
≜ṗ↔ṗb&w
```

[Crack it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HnnIc7pz9qmwIkk9TK//8HAA)

The string has 2 or fewer bytes.

> Fatalize's solution, `ẹb`, is the original string which I had intended. Note that `ẹk` also works, for the same reasons. In addition to the issue with `9001` beheading to `001`=`1`, it actually turns out that `b` on a number just won't fail, because all single digit numbers behead to `0`, including `0` itself.

Comment: That apparently useless `b` is fairly suspicious…

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188485/41723)

Answer (score 1):

## C# (.NET Core), A003678, 29727 bytes (Safe)

```
using System;using System.Linq;using System.CodeDom.Compiler;class P{static void Main(){Int32 z=0;\u0049nt32 T(\u0049nt32 i){i--;var \u0064="";for(;i>0;\u0069/=5)d=i%5+d;return d.Aggre\u0067a\u0074e(0,(a,b)=>a*5+b%48*2%5)+1;}System.D\u0069agn\u006fs\u0074ics.Pro\u0063ess.\u0053tart(CodeDo\u006dProvi\u0064er.\u0043reateP\u0072ovider("CSharp").Co\u006dpi\u006ceAssembly\u0046romSource(new Com\u0070ile\u0072P\u0061ra\u006det\u0065rs(new[]{"System.dll"}){GenerateExecutable=true,\u0047enerateI\u006e\u004de\u006dor\u0079=false,Out\u0070utAs\u0073\u0065m\u0062\u006cy="One.exe"},Stri\u006eg.Con\u0063at(@"5FKX4&4A@6W]4V0).7K]073W:J7`1G?V4H;T1*'V.VD).7K]073W:J7`1G?V4H;T1*'V.VD)8F'[4FOX3V/_.:0&?FK]:I?_2FL*?G?X?X\+1&8T:IDU0746;&\+?FTA3XL&3XL=B'L:8T\V*W3V5X[TB'L:8T[Y?6/T1*T-8X?A?6P_5H@:*ET&/ZT-8X?>)W3X4X0C.7DU2(\&3XL&9G0&*W3V5X[T1*T-8X?A*60I?G;V1FPU?V06:Z,S?X`C.7DU2(\_5H@:*J0&B'L:8T\V9G0=3T`'/WPA/6D_5H@:*DWVA&W^/U`_5H@:*DPV3Z+_?JT-8X??*67[4(0B/V;W:Y#P5*+_:G0&B'L:8TL=B'L:8TL=B'L:8TL=3XKB4&0.:F'[?60KB'L:8T[>4J#VB'L:8TT;=&0*0ZT-8X?A0J'a<J,)/T`B=(`G@V0*5FT'A&W^/T`'/WPA/6DTB'L:8T[>A*T-8X??.&OV@V/Y/VSV4*/V7W?`1V/[0H/H4*T-8X??*4L;;)#b.70&9HL=B'L:8T\V9H<J?FTU4F0_5H@:*$WV2&L9+:(T7W3V5X[T1*T-8X?A*60J?JT-8X??9*,_5H@:*J'V4V/_B'L:8TW@/Z0&?FTU4ZT-8X?A.*T-8X?A0G3U56O_B'L:8T[>B'L:8TS=1F7[4(0*26OV1&<6,:T-8X?A/W?=9)$G:WHB;)#P3ZT-8X?A?XL=B'L:8TL=3XL9+7@*B'L:8TT;0:$_5H@:*$P_5H@:*$WV1D`6=&0)?&/_+:T-8X??*7?_B'L:8T[OB'L:8T\;5G?V1I#=.70_5H@:*J0=9HL&9H<_5H@:)TL*?G?V4JT-8X?A)W4*1H;D?:T-8X?A*:T-8X?>9*,_5H@:*F/W/X0'/WPA/6DT/ZT-8X?>)G@U4V0)/W4*A:Ka4&0.:F'[?6/T1'4T07?X1'4X4Z,*/ZT-8X?A?60'4X0'/WPA/6DT/ZT-8X?@9*T-8X?A.'4_5H@:*HL_5H@:*(C`=6OV2*,*1*T-8X??9&,,1VSV1FKXB'L:8T[Y4(0'/WPA/6DT/U'_0*T-8X??)ZT-8X?A?60'4Z?V0JT-8X?A)VSVB'L:8T[VB'L:8T[=B'L:8T[>/GG^2&/]1F7[4(0B58`C<&(_5H@:*F<T/ZT-8X?@9&8'B'L:8T\=B'L:8TT;B'L:8TSO=6OV2*,*B'L:8T[Y2*D_5H@:*%S^/X<H/ZT-8X??)FL_5H@:)TWZ?G4G4&0.:JT-8X?@)FDT/ZT-8X?>8VSX4F8*07CV/GG^2&/]1JT-8X?A.&D'7XLC;)4'/WPA/6DTB'L:8T[>=&0*0VDT@V0_5H@:*$X-2*T-8X?A/Z8*?JT-8X??*60)/W4_5H@:*$X64&0.:F'[?60J2&8)07?X5&/U56O_/ZT-8X??)FKX1'468Y$C;)4'/WPA/6DT/YLU2*T-8X?A.*,SB'L:8T\V/U_VB'L:8T[=B'L:8T\VB'L:8T\=B'L:8TT;?G?X1'4X4Z,_5H@:*$WV4F0_5H@:*F0_5H@:*$X64VW^/VCY7ZT-8X?@.'4*)HDC<(`U:Y4'/WPA/6DT/Y?_07;X4V8+/ZT-8X?@)ZT-8X??-6O_/VL_5H@:*$KX1*T-8X?A/X0:;)$G4&0.:F'[?:T-8X?A)U8_5H@:*$WV2*,*06D'@:T-8X??*:T-8X?A9G?V4F0_5H@:*F0*7W3V5X[T1*(_5H@:*DPM?FSX?J$&/U_V?W0U2*,*06D'@7@UB'L:8TS@/ZT-8X?A?60'B'L:8TS@7W?`1V/[0H/H4*T-8X??*4L;;)4B4X`G4&0.:F'[?:T-8X?A)Y?_07<_5H@:*ET*07CVB'L:8TW>56O_B'L:8T[>1FKX1'469I$C<'3V5X[T1*'V.F8'B'L:8T\=2&X_5H@:*6;^/VTU4ZT-8X?A0FT_5H@:*4P,B'L:8TT:2&/]1F8_5H@:*F<'7W3V5X[T1*'VB'L:8TOA?JT-8X??9&8_5H@:*HL_5H@:*HD&/Z?V0F/_/W4V/V,,1VSV1FKX1'46:W@B;)3T1*T-8X?A*6/QB'L:8T[O4*+_2:T-8X?@0FOV2*,*1&T_5H@:)TW`1V09<:T-8X?A)VL_5H@:*$L[B'L:8T[L?G4LB'L:8TT;B'L:8TW>17L_5H@:*HL&<'3V5X[T1*'V=J,_5H@:*(CX?J$&/Z@_5H@:*DOY/VSV4*/VB'L:8TW>56O_/VK]0:T-8X?A0G46:WHB;)$G4&0.:F'[?60_5H@:*8K]1JT-8X?A.&4_5H@:*F0XB'L:8TS@?G?V4F0'4X0'/WPA/6DT/YLUB'L:8TT;0:,SB'L:8T\V/Z?V0F/_/W4V/V,,1VT_5H@:*DP_5H@:*$K]06D'7X`*:Y$G4&0.:F'[B'L:8T[@/ZT-8X?@9&8'?FS`=6P_5H@:*DO_?JT-8X??*6C_B'L:8TW>B'L:8TSL1VSV1JT-8X??)F8_5H@:*F<'7W3V5X[T1*T-8X?A*60M?FT_5H@:*ETU?'/VB'L:8TP;B'L:8T[>0F0_5H@:*(CV4*/V/GG^B'L:8TT;/ZT-8X??)FKX1'46:W@B;)4_5H@:*4K[?6/Q074U2*T-8X??.)G^/VTUB'L:8TS@1*T-8X??9*C`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`B'L:8TT:/Z?V0F/_/W4VB'L:8T[>/GG^2&/]1JT-8X?A.*T-8X?A0G46:Z7`1G?V4H<K?G?Z:Y$G:Y7[0(`C<'3V5X[T1*'V+6SWB'L:8TS>4F0'4Z@_5H@:*DOY/VT_5H@:*DP'?ZT-8X?A)V,,1VSVB'L:8TS=B'L:8TS=06D'7X`*:Y$G4&0.:F'[?60J2*T-8X?A.'<_5H@:*ET*07CV/GH_5H@:*(?_B'L:8T[>B'L:8TS=1F8_5H@:*F<'7TLC;)3T1*'V.F8'?FS`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`=:T-8X??8V/_?G@_5H@:*F;_/GG^2&/]1F7[4(0'/WPA/6DT/ZT-8X?>*JT-8X?A9FSX?J$&/Z@_5H@:*DOY/VSVB'L:8T[V?V/UB'L:8TSL1VSV1FKX1*T-8X?A/X0B58`C<&(_5H@:*F<T/U\_5H@:*ET'B'L:8T\=2*T-8X??.)G^/VTU4ZT-8X?A0FT_5H@:)TX_5H@:*%S^/X<KB'L:8T[Y?7L_5H@:*J0_5H@:*$O]<'3V5X[T1*'V=J,_5H@:*(D_5H@:*ETU?'/V@V/YB'L:8T[>2&0'?V/U56O_/VK]06D'7X`*:Y$C<*T-8X?@)FDT/U[X4*,_5H@:*(C`=6OV2*,*1&T_5H@:)TW`B'L:8TT:/X;HB'L:8T[@/W4_5H@:*$X_5H@:*ET_5H@:*$W`/JT-8X??9JT-8X??)ZT-8X?A9G/XB'L:8TS@294'/WPAB'L:8TW=1*'V<VSX4F8*0:T-8X??*JT-8X?A)V,,1ZT-8X??9&/]1F7[B'L:8T[V7X@C;)$G4&0.:F'[?6/D1FL_5H@:*ESW4*8_5H@:*$XU4V0)B'L:8T[>4'@64&0.:F'[?:T-8X?A)ZT-8X?>*J+_0:,S3V0_5H@:)XCV0JT-8X?A)VSVB'L:8T[VB'L:8T[=/V,,1VSV1FKX1'46:Z,B;)4'/WPA/:T-8X?A0J'V=J+_0:,S3V0Z/V;V2&0'?V0_5H@:*4P,1VT_5H@:*DO]1F7[4(0B4X`C;)$C<'3V5X\_5H@:*4K[?60M?JT-8X??9*T-8X?A.*T-8X?A9JT-8X?A9'/V.ZT-8X?A)Z0&?JT-8X??9*,*0:T-8X?A0JT-8X?A/Z8*?G?V4F0'B'L:8TS@7W?`1V/[0H/H4'?=9)$G:Z(U1H`G4&0.:F'[?:T-8X?A)YLU2&8U?'/V@V0_5H@:*D[V2&0_5H@:*F0V/V,,1VSV1FKXB'L:8T[Y4(0B58`C;)4'/WPA/:T-8X?A0J'VB'L:8TWOB'L:8TS@/VTU4ZT-8X?A.*T-8X?A0G4X4Z,*B'L:8T[>4F0'B'L:8TS@7W3V5X\_5H@:*4K[?60_5H@:*8K]1JT-8X?A.&4_5H@:*F0X4Z,*/W;V4'@64&0.:F'[?60M?FSX?J$&/ZT-8X?>9&/YB'L:8T[>2&0'?ZT-8X?A)V,,1ZT-8X??9&/]1JT-8X?A.&D'7X`T?FLB;)4'/WPAB'L:8TW=1*T-8X?A*60M?FT_5H@:*ETU?'/V@V0_5H@:*D\_5H@:*DO_B'L:8T[>4*/VB'L:8TW>56P_5H@:*(D_5H@:*DO]1F7[4(0B?:+]:Y$C<'3V5X[T1*T-8X?A*60_5H@:*8D_5H@:*ET'B'L:8T\=2&XLB'L:8TT:/ZT-8X??9*,_5H@:*$W[2&,,1VSV1JT-8X??)JT-8X?A.&D'7W3V5X[T1*'VB'L:8TX;0:T-8X?A/Z+_B'L:8TSOB'L:8TWYB'L:8TT:B'L:8T[>2*,*1*T-8X??9&,,1VSV1FKX1'464&0.:F'[?:T-8X?A)YLU2&8U?'/VB'L:8TP;/V;V2&0'B'L:8T[=/V,,1VSV1FKXB'L:8T[Y4(0B?:+]:Y$G/6DT/U[X4*+_29G^B'L:8T[>2*,*1*T-8X??9*C`1ZT-8X?A)X<K1*(_5H@:*$P&5FLG4&0.:F'[?60J2&8)07?X5&/U56P_5H@:*(CV1JT-8X??)F7[4(/=;)$G/6D_5H@:*DWV.F8'?FS`=:T-8X??8V/_B'L:8T\=4VC_A&W^/X;H?:T-8X?A)ZT-8X?A/W?X4ZT-8X??.&+\5J,&07?`<'3V5X[TB'L:8T[YB'L:8T[@B'L:8T[><VSX4JT-8X?A.'?XB'L:8TSAB'L:8T[>/GG^2&/]1JT-8X?A.&D'7X@C;)4'/WPA/6DT/ZT-8X?@9FK]B'L:8T[O0'4X4Z,*/W;V4'@64&0.:F(_5H@:*F<T/ZT-8X?>*J+_0:,_5H@:*HD&/Z@_5H@:*DOY/VSVB'L:8T[V?V/U56O_/VK]0:T-8X?A0G46:Z(U1H`C<'3V5X[T1*'V.F8'?FS`=6OV2*,_5H@:*$W[2&,_5H@:*%G^2&/]B'L:8TS=06D'7W3V5X[TB'L:8T[Y?:T-8X?A)YLUB'L:8TT;0:,S3V0Z/V;V2*T-8X?A)W4_5H@:*DKV/GG^2&/]1F8_5H@:*F<'7X`T?FLB;)3T1*(_5H@:*DOQ074U2&XL1V/_B'L:8T\=4VC_B'L:8TO@2:T-8X??8V09.V8+B'L:8T[O?60G4&0.:F'[?:T-8X?A)Y?_07;X4ZT-8X?A.'CV/GG^B'L:8TT;B'L:8T[>1FKX1'46)I$C;)$G4&0.:F'[B'L:8T[@/YLU2&8U?*T-8X?A?V/R/Z0&?FTUB'L:8TS@06D'@7@U4V0)/ZT-8X?A/W@64VW^/VCY7U8'4TL;;)4B?8`G4&0.:F'[?60J2&8)07?X5&/U56O_/VL_5H@:*$KX1'468Y$C<'3V5X[T1*T-8X?A*60MB'L:8T\=2&8_5H@:*HLS3V/R/Z0_5H@:*J0_5H@:*HK_B'L:8T\=4ZT-8X?A.*T-8X?A0JT-8X?A/Z8*B'L:8T\=4V0_5H@:*J'V4'@64VW^/VCY7U8'4TL;;)4B48`G4&0.:F(_5H@:*F<T/ZT-8X?>*J+_0:,S3V0Z/V;V2&0'?V/U5:T-8X??8VSV1JT-8X??)F7[4(0B?:+]:Y$C<'3V5X[T1*'VB'L:8TOA?FSX?J$&/U_V?W0UB'L:8TT;?JT-8X??*:T-8X?A.&D'@:T-8X??*:,_5H@:*$WV4JT-8X?A)W4*7W?`1V/[0H0_5H@:)TL*2&8'B'L:8T[?;)4B1X`G4&0.:F'[?60_5H@:)X?_07;X4V8+B'L:8T[>B'L:8TW>5:T-8X??8VSV1FL_5H@:*ES[4(0B:Y$C<'3V5X\_5H@:*4L_5H@:*F<TB'L:8T[>,7?V2*,*B'L:8T[O1'4_5H@:)TL_5H@:*$XU4V0)/W4*7W3V5X[T1*'VB'L:8TX=1FL_5H@:*ESW4*8*?G?V4F0_5H@:*F0*7W3V5X\_5H@:*4K[?60M?FSX?J$&/Z@_5H@:*DP_5H@:*D[V2&0'?V/U56P_5H@:*(CV1FKX1'46:Z(U1H`C<'3V5X[T1*'VB'L:8TOA?FSXB'L:8T\=?*T-8X?A?V0Z/ZT-8X?A*F/_/W4VB'L:8T[>/GG^2*T-8X?A)VK]B'L:8T[O1'46:Z(U1H`C;)4'/WPAB'L:8TW=1*(_5H@:*DOQ074_5H@:*HK_29G^/VTUB'L:8TS@1*T-8X??9*T-8X?@)ZT-8X??-6O_B'L:8T[>1FKXB'L:8T[Y4(0'/WPA/6D_5H@:*DWV=J,_5H@:*(CX?J$&/Z?V0JT-8X?A)ZT-8X??9&0'B'L:8T[=/ZT-8X?@)WG^2*T-8X?A)ZT-8X??)JT-8X??)F7[B'L:8T[V7X`(:Y$GB'L:8TW=1*(_5H@:*DOQ074U2&XLB'L:8TT:/VTU4VD_5H@:*(D_5H@:)TW`1V09,&SV?G?V2*CZ?G4G4&0.:F'[B'L:8T[@B'L:8T[><ZT-8X??9&8)B'L:8T[O4V8+/V,,1VSV1FKX1'468Y$C<'3V5X[T1*T-8X?A*:T-8X?A)U']1JT-8X?A.&4'@7@_5H@:*HL*/W<_5H@:*DP'4X0'/WPAB'L:8TW=1*'VB'L:8TOAB'L:8T\=2*T-8X?A.*,SB'L:8T\VB'L:8T[>@V/Y/VSV4*T-8X?A)F/U56O_/VK]06D'7X`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`1V09+:(_5H@:*DXG4&0.:F'[?60M?FSX?J$&/Z?V0F/_B'L:8T[>B'L:8T[V?V0_5H@:*4P,1VT_5H@:*DO]1F8_5H@:*F<'7X_^:Y$C;)$G4&0.:F'[B'L:8T[@/U(_5H@:*$K]B'L:8T[O0'4X4ZT-8X?A9JT-8X??*:T-8X?A)W<_5H@:*DP'4X0'/WPA/6DT/YLU2&8U?'0_5H@:*DPZ/V;V2&0'?V/UB'L:8TSL1VSV1FKX1*T-8X?A/X0B1X`C<'3V5X[TB'L:8T[Y?:T-8X?A)YCV4V@_5H@:*F<T,74+1'7VB'L:8TW>56O_/VK]06D'7W3V5X[T1*'V=J+_0:,_5H@:*HD&/Z?V0F/_/ZT-8X?A/Z/V/JT-8X??-6O_/VL_5H@:*$KX1'46:VPB;)4BA&SX4J8*?FT*:Y4'/WPAB'L:8TW=1*T-8X?A*60J2&8)B'L:8T[O4V8+/V,,1VSVB'L:8TS=1F7[4(088X8C;)$G4&0.:JT-8X?@)FD_5H@:*DWVB'L:8TWOB'L:8TS@/VTUB'L:8TS@06D'@7@U4V0_5H@:*J(_5H@:*DP'4X0'/WPA/6DT/ZT-8X?>*J+_0:T-8X?A9JT-8X?A9'/VB'L:8TW@/Z0&?FTU4V7[4*8*?JT-8X??*60)/W4*7W?`1V/[0H/HB'L:8T[V4TL_5H@:)HDC<(_X:Y4'/WPA/:T-8X?A0J'VB'L:8TP:B'L:8TT;07;X4ZT-8X?A.'CV/GG^2&/]B'L:8TS=06D'7X@C;)4'/WPAB'L:8TW=1*(_5H@:*DOQ074_5H@:*HK_B'L:8TSO=6OV2*,*B'L:8T[YB'L:8TT;B'L:8TW>5:T-8X??8ZT-8X??9*T-8X?A)VK]B'L:8T[O1'464&0.:F'[?60M?FSX?JT-8X?A9'/V@ZT-8X?A)V;V2&0_5H@:*F0_5H@:*DL_5H@:*DP_5H@:*4P,B'L:8TT:2&/]B'L:8TS=06D'7X_X:Y$G/6D_5H@:*DWV.F8'?FS`=6P_5H@:*DP_5H@:*(DU4ZT-8X?A0FT[26OV8I7V1FL[0Z,_5H@:*F0G4&0.:F(_5H@:*F<T/Y?_1&OV2'@_5H@:*%TZ/ZT-8X?A*F/_B'L:8T[>B'L:8T[V?V0_5H@:*4P,1ZT-8X??9&/]1JT-8X?A.&D_5H@:*F064&0.:F'[?:T-8X?A)YLU2&8_5H@:*HLS3V0_5H@:)XCV0F/_/W4_5H@:*DKV/JT-8X??-6P_5H@:*(CV1JT-8X??)JT-8X?A.&D'7X_^:Y$G:Y7V4&4*0X`C;)4'/WPA/6D_5H@:*DWV+6K]064'@7@U4V0)/W4*7W3V5X[TB'L:8T[Y?60MB'L:8T\=B'L:8TT;B'L:8T[O?J$&/Z?V0F/_/W4V/V,_5H@:*%G^2&/]B'L:8TS=06D'7X_X:Y$G4&0.:JT-8X?@)FDTB'L:8T[>.F8'?FS`=6OVB'L:8TT;?G?[2&,,1VSV1FKXB'L:8T[YB'L:8T[V7W3V5X[T1*(_5H@:*DP_5H@:)T\_5H@:*HK_B'L:8T[O?J$&/Z?V0F/_B'L:8T[>4*/VB'L:8TW>56O_/VL_5H@:*$KX1'46:V8B;)3T1*'V.F8'?FS`=6OV2*,*1&T_5H@:)TW`1V09+:(T<'3V5X[T1*'V<ZT-8X??9&8)07?X5&/U56O_/VK]06D_5H@:*F069I$C;)4'/WPA/6DT/ZT-8X?@9JT-8X??)FKXB'L:8T[?4*T-8X?>)G@_5H@:*HL*B'L:8T[>4F0_5H@:*F0*7W3V5X\_5H@:*4K[?60M?FT_5H@:*ETUB'L:8T\;3V0Z/V;V2*T-8X?A)W4V/V,,1VSV1FKX1'46:Z(B;)4'/WPA/6D_5H@:*DWVB'L:8TX;074U2&XL1V/_?G@_5H@:*F;_/JT-8X??-:T-8X??8ZT-8X??9&/]1JT-8X?A.&D'7W3V5X\_5H@:*4K[?60_5H@:)T\U2&8U?*T-8X?A?V0Z/ZT-8X?A*F/_B'L:8T[>4*0_5H@:*DOU56O_/ZT-8X??)FKXB'L:8T[YB'L:8T[V7X`T:Y$GB'L:8TW=1*'V.F8'?FT_5H@:*%TL1ZT-8X?A)VT_5H@:*HL*1*T-8X??9*C`1V09+:(T<'3V5X\_5H@:*4K[?6/Q0:T-8X?A/Z+_B'L:8TSO=6P_5H@:*DP_5H@:*(DU4VC_/GG^2&/]1F7[B'L:8T[V7W3V5X[T1*'V.JT-8X?A.'4U2*T-8X??.)G^/ZT-8X??9*,*1&SUB'L:8TSL1VSV1JT-8X??)F8_5H@:*F<'7W3V5X[TB'L:8T[Y?:T-8X?A)ZT-8X?@9JT-8X??9&T_5H@:*HK`,74T/WH_5H@:*DO_B'L:8TW>56O_B'L:8T[>1FKX1'464&0.:F'[B'L:8T[@/YLUB'L:8TT;0:,S3V0Z/V<_5H@:*DO_B'L:8T[>4*/V/GG^2&/]1F7[4(0B1X`C<'3V5X[T1*'VB'L:8TOAB'L:8T\=B'L:8TT;0:,S3ZT-8X?A)Z@_5H@:*DOY/VSVB'L:8T[V?V0_5H@:*4P,1VT_5H@:*DO]1F7[4(0B08`C;)3T1*(_5H@:*DOQ074_5H@:*HL_5H@:*(C`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`=:T-8X??8V0_5H@:*(DU4VC_/GG^2*T-8X?A)ZT-8X??)FL_5H@:*ES[4(0'/WPAB'L:8TW=1*'V=J,_5H@:*(CX?J$&B'L:8T[>@V/YB'L:8T[>2&0_5H@:*F0V/V,,B'L:8TT:2&/]B'L:8TS=06D_5H@:*F06:Z(B;)3T1*'V.F8_5H@:*F0U2&XL1V/_B'L:8T\=4VD_5H@:*(D[2:T-8X??8V09='L&4V7^3VXG4&0.:JT-8X?@)FDT/ZT-8X?>*J+_0:,S3V0Z/V;V2&0'B'L:8T[=B'L:8T[>B'L:8TW>56P_5H@:*(CV1FKX1'46:Z,B;)$C2Y#P5*+_:G0=3XL&9HKB4&0.:F'[?:T-8X?A)YCVB'L:8T\TB'L:8T\;/VTK/W?ZB'L:8T[Y?6\I?G;V*X`H1&4B<*?V4WK_4*C`1V/B4&0.:F(_5H@:*F<_5H@:*DWVB'L:8TO@B'L:8TSO1V0Z/ZT-8X?A*JT-8X?A)VSV4*0_5H@:*DP64VW^/VCY7ZT-8X?@*6D-?'/V;)$GB'L:8TX=4W?_0:T-8X?A9'L*B'L:8T[>1D`6=&0_5H@:*J(_5H@:*HCV2%(*4ZT-8X??9&8S5G@_5H@:*DO];&,'B'L:8TS>B'L:8T\T8JT-8X?>8Z+_1JT-8X?A)X0*26OV1&<6=&0_5H@:*J(_5H@:*HCV2*T-8X?@9JT-8X??*7?_B'L:8T[O?'L*/VLC<&,'5JT-8X?A?8;G/W@I?JT-8X?A?6/]7W?`1V/[0H0_5H@:*:'V4J#VB'L:8TT;+7@*2&8S5G@_5H@:*DO];)$\9*LC2UX_5H@:*J0=3XL&9HL9<Z+_?G<_5H@:*DP*/VS]8E(_5H@:*DXT7W3V5X\_5H@:*4L_5H@:*F<_5H@:*DWV<ZT-8X?A9JT-8X??9*,_5H@:*J'V4V/_.V0V3Z+_?JT-8X??*:T-8X?A.*T-8X?A0G3U56O_/VL_5H@:*$KX1'464VW^/VCY7U`_5H@:*F<-?'/V;)4B58`C;%X&9G0=3XL=8I@U2*,)/W?VB'L:8TT;B'L:8TS=8E(_5H@:*DXT7W3V5X[TB'L:8T[Y?60_5H@:)X@U2*,)/ZT-8X??*:T-8X?A)VSR/Z0&?FTU4V7[4*T-8X?@)WG^2&/]B'L:8TS=B'L:8T[O1'464VW^/VCY7U8'4ZT-8X?=)HDC<(`':Y$C.70_5H@:)HL&9G0_5H@:)HL=8J8*B'L:8T\=4V0)/W4_5H@:*$X_5H@:*$L9+:(T@Z,'0&064&0.:F'[?60XB'L:8TS@?G?VB'L:8T\T/W4*A:Ka4&0.:F'[?60M?JT-8X??9&8U?*T-8X?A?V/R/Z0&?FT_5H@:*HL*06D'@7@U4V0)/W4*7W?`1V/[0H/H4'?=9)$G:WLB<'3V5X[T1*'V=&0_5H@:*$WZB'L:8T[YB'L:8T[@,:T-8X?A/WC[46/U56P_5H@:*(CVB'L:8TS=B'L:8TS=06D'7W3V5X[T1*'V=&0*0VDT@V0_5H@:*D\_5H@:*DP_5H@:*(CV4*/V/GG^2&/]1F7[B'L:8T[V7W3V5X[T1*'VA&W^/Z?VB'L:8T[A/VSV4*0_5H@:*DOU56P_5H@:*(D_5H@:*DO]1F7[B'L:8T[V7X_V0F4B;)4B=(`C<'3V5X[T1*'V=JT-8X?A9FSXB'L:8T\=?'/V@V/Y/ZT-8X??9&0_5H@:*F0V/ZT-8X?@)ZT-8X??-:T-8X??8VSV1JT-8X??)F7[4(0B4(`C;)$G4&0.:F(_5H@:*F<TB'L:8T[>=J+_0:T-8X?A9JT-8X?A9'/VB'L:8TW@/Z0_5H@:*J0U2*,*06D'@7@UB'L:8TS@/ZT-8X?A?60'4X0*26OV1&<6.VD-?'/V;)4B1(`G4&0.:JT-8X?@)JT-8X?A0J'V<VSX4F8*07D_5H@:*DOU56O_/VK]06D_5H@:*F069I$C<'3V5X[T1*'VB'L:8TWO4V/_?G@_5H@:*ES[4*8_5H@:*$XU4V0_5H@:*J'V4'@64&0.:F'[B'L:8T[@/YL_5H@:*HK_B'L:8T[O?J$_5H@:*J/V.V0_5H@:*DL_5H@:*J0UB'L:8TT;B'L:8T\=B'L:8TS@06D_5H@:*F0XB'L:8TS@?G?V4F0'B'L:8TS@7W?`1V/[0H/HB'L:8T[V4TL_5H@:)HDC<(_X:Y4'/WPAB'L:8TW=1*(_5H@:*DPJ2*T-8X?A.';X4V8+B'L:8T[>/GG^2*T-8X?A)ZT-8X??)FKX1'468Y$C<'3V5X[TB'L:8T[YB'L:8T[@/U[X4*+_2:T-8X?@0FP_5H@:*DP_5H@:*(D_5H@:*HL*1&T_5H@:*4P,1VT_5H@:*DO]1F8_5H@:*F<'7W3V5X[T1*T-8X?A*60M?JT-8X??9&8U?'/V@V/Y/ZT-8X??9*T-8X?A)W4VB'L:8T[>/GG^2&/]B'L:8TS=06D_5H@:*F06:V8B;)3T1*'VB'L:8TX;074U2*T-8X??.)H_5H@:*(?VB'L:8TT;?G?[B'L:8TT;A&W^/X<H/ZT-8X??)FL[0Z,_5H@:*F0G4&0.:F'[?60M?FSX?J$&/ZT-8X?>9&/Y/VSVB'L:8T[VB'L:8T[=/ZT-8X?@)WG^2&/]1F7[4(0B5H`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`=:T-8X??8V/_?G@_5H@:*F<_5H@:*(CU56O_/VK]B'L:8T[O1'464&0.:F(_5H@:*F<_5H@:*DWV=J,_5H@:*(D_5H@:*ETUB'L:8T\;3V0Z/V;V2&0'?V0_5H@:*4P,1VSV1FKX1*T-8X?A/X0B1(`C<*T-8X?@)FDT/U[X4*+_29G^B'L:8T[>2*T-8X?A9G?[2*T-8X?>*6X_5H@:*(?V8ID-3W?X1ZT-8X?A?ZT-8X??.)4'/WPA/6DT/U'_0'L)/ZT-8X?A/ZT-8X??*:?V0F0_5H@:*(CV4*/V/GG^B'L:8TT;/VK]B'L:8T[O1'46:WHB;)$C;)4'/WPA/6DT/YCVB'L:8TS@0VDT@V0_5H@:*$X-2'4X4ZT-8X?A9G?V4F0'B'L:8TS@7W3V5X[T1*'VB'L:8TOAB'L:8T\=2&8U?'/V@V/YB'L:8T[>2&0'?ZT-8X?A)V,,B'L:8TT:2*T-8X?A)ZT-8X??)FKX1*T-8X?A/X0B1(`C;&`C.7DU2(\&3W0_5H@:)HL_5H@:*J0=B'L:8TL=*W3V5X[TB'L:8T[YB'L:8T[@/V(_5H@:*F<'1G?_5J0*B'L:8T[Y2(0C.70_5H@:*J0_5H@:*J0=3ZT-8X?=9JT-8X?=9H<X4Z,*/W;VB'L:8T[V4VL9+:(_5H@:*DX64&0.:F'[?60K/W?Z1*'HB'L:8T[V5&D_5H@:*J#VB'L:8TW>56O_/VK]06D'7W3V5X\_5H@:*4K[?6/D2*T-8X??9*T-8X?A9FWH4*'V56/_B'L:8TW>5:T-8X??8VSV1FKX1*T-8X?A/X0'/WPA/6DTB'L:8T[>B'L:8TXTB'L:8T[>4V?[?58_5H@:*F0_5H@:*$[[B'L:8T\S/V,_5H@:*%G^2&/]B'L:8TS=0:T-8X?A0G464&0.:F'[?:T-8X?A)ZC`1V0L0F,,1ZT-8X??9&/]1JT-8X?A.*T-8X?A0G464VW^/VCY7U[[1'/V?G4C;)4B,&0*/&7V3Z']:Y$G4&0.:F'[?60JB'L:8TT;B'L:8T[O4F8*07CV/GH_5H@:*(?_/ZT-8X??)JT-8X??)JT-8X?A.&D'7XLC;)4B@60*=J,&5F0B<'3V5X\_5H@:*4L_5H@:*F<TB'L:8T[>B'L:8TP:2&8)0:T-8X??*68+/V,_5H@:*%G^2&/]1F7[4(0'5G0&;)4'/WPA/6DT/ZT-8X?>8VSXB'L:8T\T07?X5&0_5H@:*4P,1VSVB'L:8TS=1JT-8X?A.&D'7X_D.J?D/5'R+5\Z+5'Q@U(B;)$C.7DU2(\&9HL=3W0_5H@:)HKB4&0.:JT-8X?@)FDTB'L:8T[>=&0)?&/_=&0*0VD_5H@:*DWa@V0*5FT'A&W^/T`'/WPA/6DT/ZC`1ZT-8X?A)Z?V0F0_5H@:*(CVB'L:8T[V?V064VW^/VCY7U_[B'L:8TS>?'0_5H@:*DPC;)4IB'L:8T\=B'L:8T\T/T`B0H_b.70=B'L:8TL=9JT-8X?A?W0_5H@:)HL9<Z+_?G;V4ZT-8X?A)VS]8JT-8X?@9J(T7W3V5X\_5H@:*4K[?:T-8X?A)Y@U2*,)/W?V2%`_5H@:*DPV3Z+_?G?XB'L:8T[Y4&,,1VT_5H@:*DP_5H@:*$K]0:T-8X?A0JT-8X?A/X0*26OV1&<6.ZT-8X?A0GL_5H@:*HD&/Y$G:Z(B;)#P3ZT-8X?=9HL=3W0=8J8*?G?V4F0_5H@:*F0*1H;D?:(64&0.:F'[?60M?FSXB'L:8T\=?*T-8X?A?V/R/Z0&?FTU4V7[4*8*?G?VB'L:8T\T/W4*7W?`1V/[0H/RB'L:8T[YB'L:8TS>?'/V;)4B58`G4&0.:F(_5H@:*F<T/U[XB'L:8T[V?FS`=6OV2*,*B'L:8T[YB'L:8TT;/JT-8X??-:T-8X??8VSVB'L:8TS=1F8_5H@:*F<'7W3V5X\_5H@:*4K[?6/Q074UB'L:8TT;29H_5H@:*(?VB'L:8TT;?G?[2&,_5H@:*%H_5H@:*(?_/ZT-8X??)FL_5H@:*ES[4(0'/WPA/6DT/Y?_B'L:8T[YB'L:8TT:/VT*B'L:8TSO@V/Y/VSV4*0_5H@:*DOU56O_B'L:8T[>1FKX1'464&0.:F'[B'L:8T[@/V#XB'L:8T[>3Z(Z/V;V2&0'?V/U5:T-8X??8VSV1FL_5H@:*ES[B'L:8T[V7W3V5X[T1*'VA&W^/Z?V0F/_B'L:8T[>B'L:8T[VB'L:8T[=/V,_5H@:*%G^2&/]1F7[4(0*26OV1&<6.FC[3V0U4)$C<(_S?G/]/Z8*2&8'0(`C<(`H/W3W4V@B;)3T1*(_5H@:*DOQ074U2&XLB'L:8TT:/VTU4VC_A&W^/X<_5H@:*4WX5&8T/Y4'/WPA/6DTB'L:8T[><VSX4F8*07CV/JT-8X??-:T-8X??8VSV1JT-8X??)F8_5H@:*F<_5H@:*F069HDT;)$G/6D_5H@:*DWVB'L:8TX;074_5H@:*HK_2:T-8X?@0FOV2*,_5H@:*$W[2*D_5H@:*%S^B'L:8T[>8ID_5H@:*$P_5H@:*J0*06P&294'/WPA/6DT/YCV4V@_5H@:*F<T,74+1'7V/GG^2&/]1JT-8X?A.*T-8X?A0G464&0.:F(_5H@:*F<T/ZC`1V0Z/ZT-8X?A*F0_5H@:*(CV4*/V/GH_5H@:*(?_/VL_5H@:*$KX1'46:Z7`1G?V4H<K?G?Z:Y$G:Z?[5G4T:Y4'/WPA/:T-8X?A0J'V<VSXB'L:8T\T07?X5&0_5H@:*4P,1VSV1FKX1*T-8X?A/X0:?9$G4&0.:F'[?60J2&8)07?XB'L:8TSAB'L:8T[>/GG^2&/]1F7[B'L:8T[V7XLC;)$C;%X&9HL=B'L:8T\VB'L:8T\V9H<X4Z,_5H@:*$WV4F0'B'L:8TS@1H;D?:T-8X?A*80'/WPA/6D_5H@:*DWVB'L:8TXT/ZT-8X??*6?[?:?V4ZT-8X??)VT'@7@_5H@:*HL*/ZT-8X?A?60'B'L:8TS@7W3V5X[T1*(_5H@:*DOQ074U2&XL1V/_?JT-8X??*6C_/GG^2*T-8X?A)VK]06D'7W3V5X[TB'L:8T[YB'L:8T[@/U[X4*+_29G^/VTU4VD_5H@:*(CU56O_/VK]06D'7W3V5X[T1*T-8X?A*:T-8X?A)U[X4*+_29G^/VTU4VD_5H@:*(CUB'L:8TSL1VT_5H@:*DO]B'L:8TS=06D'7W3V5X[T1*'V<VSXB'L:8T\T07?XB'L:8TSA/V,,1VSV1FL_5H@:*ES[4(/O*)$G/6DT/U[X4*T-8X?A9FS`B'L:8TWY1V0_5H@:*(DUB'L:8TS@B'L:8T[Y2*C`1ZT-8X?A)X<KB'L:8TS>B'L:8T\V4V7^3VXG4&0.:F'[?60K/ZT-8X??*6?[?:T-8X?@.'4_5H@:*$[[46/U56O_B'L:8T[>1FKX1'464&0.:F'[?60[26OVB'L:8TP;/V;V2&0_5H@:*F0_5H@:*DKV/GH_5H@:*(?_B'L:8T[>1FKX1'46:V/Y0(`C<(`H1&4B<'3V5X[TB'L:8T[Y?60M?FSX?J$_5H@:*J/VB'L:8TP;/V;VB'L:8TT;/W4V/ZT-8X?@)ZT-8X??-6P_5H@:*(CV1FKXB'L:8T[Y4(0B58`C<'3V5X[T1*'V<VSX4F8_5H@:*$WX5&/UB'L:8TSL1ZT-8X??9&/]B'L:8TS=06D'7UHC;)$G/6D_5H@:*DWV.F8'B'L:8T\=2&XLB'L:8TT:/VTU4VC_A*T-8X??.&OV8E(TB'L:8T[@<'3V5X[T1*'V.F8'B'L:8T\=2&XL1V/_?G?[2&,,1VSVB'L:8TS=1F7[B'L:8T[V7W3V5X[T1*'V.F8'B'L:8T\=B'L:8TT;29G^/ZT-8X??9*T-8X?A9G?[B'L:8TT;/JT-8X??-6O_/VK]06D_5H@:*F064&0.:JT-8X?@)JT-8X?A0J'V.F8'?FT_5H@:*%TL1ZT-8X?A)VTUB'L:8TS@1&SU56O_/VK]B'L:8T[O1'464&0.:JT-8X?@)FDT/ZT-8X?@9&8_5H@:*F0U2&XL1V/_?JT-8X??*6C_B'L:8TW>56O_/VK]06D'7W3V5X[T1*'V.F8'?FS`=6OV2*,*1&SU56O_/VL_5H@:*$L_5H@:*ES[4(0'/WPA/6DT/ZT-8X?@9&8'?FS`=6OVB'L:8TT;?G@_5H@:*F;_/GG^2&/]B'L:8TS=B'L:8T[O1'464&0.:F'[?:T-8X?A)U[X4*+_29G^/VTU4VC_/GH_5H@:*(@_5H@:*(CV1FL_5H@:*ET_5H@:*F<'7W3V5X[T1*(_5H@:*DOQ074UB'L:8TT;B'L:8TSO=6OV2*,*1*T-8X??9&,,1VT_5H@:*DO]1F7[4(0'/WPAB'L:8TW=1*'V.F8'?JT-8X??9&XL1V/_?G@_5H@:*F;_/GG^2&/]B'L:8TS=06D'7W3V5X[T1*(_5H@:*DP_5H@:)X@_5H@:*(CX4F8*B'L:8T[O5*T-8X?A)V,,1VSV1FKX1'46)H??*9$G/:T-8X?A0J'V.F8'?FS`=6P_5H@:*DO_?G?[B'L:8TT;A&X_5H@:*(?V8ID-3ZT-8X??*68_5H@:*(@&294'/WPAB'L:8TW=1*T-8X?A*60_5H@:)X@_5H@:*(CX4F8*07CV/JT-8X??-6O_/VK]B'L:8T[O1'46;HLC;)3T1*'V.F8'?FS`=6OV2*,*1&T_5H@:)TW`B'L:8TT:/X<K5G0*06P_5H@:*J/`<'3V5X[T1*(_5H@:*DPKB'L:8T[>B'L:8TS@0VD_5H@:*DWH4*T-8X??*FD(/V,_5H@:*%G^2&0_5H@:*$K]06D'7W3V5X\_5H@:*4K[?60K/W@_5H@:*EG[?:?VB'L:8T[A/VT_5H@:*DP'?V/U5:T-8X??8ZT-8X??9&/]1F7[4(0'/WPA/6D_5H@:*DWVA&W^/Z?V0F/_/W4V/ZT-8X?@)WG^2&0_5H@:*$K]06D'7X_V0F4B;)4B<6CW:Y$G4&0.:F(_5H@:*F<_5H@:*DWVB'L:8TOA?FSX?J$&B'L:8T[>@V/Y/VT_5H@:*DP'?V/UB'L:8TSLB'L:8TT:B'L:8TT;/ZT-8X??)FKX1*T-8X?A/X0B58`C<'3V5X\_5H@:*4K[B'L:8T[@/Y@_5H@:*(D_5H@:*ET)07@_5H@:*ET+/V,,1VSV1JT-8X??)F7[4(/>;)$C<&(_5H@:*F<_5H@:*DX_5H@:*DOQ074UB'L:8TT;B'L:8TSO=6OV2*,*1&T[26OV8E(T?94'/WPA/6DTB'L:8T[>.F8_5H@:*F0UB'L:8TT;29G^B'L:8T[>2*,*1*T-8X??9&,_5H@:*%G^2&/]B'L:8TS=0:T-8X?A0G464&0.:F'[?6/Q074U2&XL1V0_5H@:*(DUB'L:8TS@1&SU56O_/ZT-8X??)JT-8X??)JT-8X?A.&D_5H@:*F064&0.:JT-8X?@)FD_5H@:*DWVB'L:8TX;074UB'L:8TT;29G^/VTU4VC_/GG^2&/]1F7[4(0'/WPA/:T-8X?A0JT-8X?A*60M?FSX?J$&/Z?V0F/_/W4VB'L:8T[>/GH_5H@:*(?_/VK]06D'7X`,:Y$G/:T-8X?A0J'VB'L:8TX;074U2*T-8X??.)G^/ZT-8X??9*,*1&T[26OV8ID_5H@:*$P&4V8_5H@:*(@&B'L:8TSO<'3V5X[T1*'VB'L:8TX;074U2&XL1V/_B'L:8T\=4ZT-8X?A0JT-8X??9&,,1VT_5H@:*DO]1JT-8X?A.&D'7W3V5X[TB'L:8T[Y?:T-8X?A)YLU2&8U?'/V@V/Y/VSVB'L:8T[V?ZT-8X?A)ZT-8X?@)WG^2&/]1JT-8X?A.&D'7X`,:Y$GB'L:8TW=1*'V.F8'?JT-8X??9&XLB'L:8TT:/ZT-8X??9*,*1&T[B'L:8TSO1V09='L&4V7^B'L:8T\VB'L:8TSO<'3V5X[T1*'V<VSXB'L:8T\T0:T-8X??*:T-8X?A.'D_5H@:*DP_5H@:*4P,1VSV1FKX1'46)ES?)HDC;)$G/6DT/ZT-8X?@9&8'?FS`B'L:8TWY1V/_?G?[2*D_5H@:*%S^B'L:8T[>8ID-3W?X1W0_5H@:*%TG4&0.:JT-8X?@)FDTB'L:8T[>.F8'?FS`=6OVB'L:8TT;B'L:8T\=4ZT-8X?A0FSU56O_/VK]06D'7W3V5X[T1*'V.F8'?FS`=6P_5H@:*DO_?JT-8X??*6D_5H@:*(CU56O_/VK]06D'7W3V5X[TB'L:8T[Y?:T-8X?A)YLUB'L:8TT;0:T-8X?A9J$&/Z?V0F/_/W4V/V,,B'L:8TT:2&/]1F7[4(0B58`C<&'[?:T-8X?A)U[XB'L:8T[V?JT-8X??9&XL1V/_?JT-8X??*6D_5H@:*(D[B'L:8TSO1V09='L&B'L:8TS@06P&B'L:8TSO<'3V5X[T1*'V=J,_5H@:*(CX?J$_5H@:*J/VB'L:8TP;/V;V2&0_5H@:*F0V/V,,1VT_5H@:*DO]1F7[4(0B58`C;)3T1*'V.F8'?FT_5H@:*%T_5H@:*6<_5H@:*(?V2*,*B'L:8T[Y2*C`1V09B'L:8TXT5G0_5H@:*$WX1W/`<'3V5X\_5H@:*4K[?60M?JT-8X??9*T-8X?A.*,S3V0Z/V;VB'L:8TT;/W4V/ZT-8X?@)WH_5H@:*(@_5H@:*(CV1FKX1'46:WHB;)$C<*T-8X?@)JT-8X?A0JT-8X?A*60_5H@:*8CX4*+_2:T-8X?@0JT-8X??8ZT-8X?A)VTU4VC_B'L:8TO@26P_5H@:*DP9B'L:8TXT5G0_5H@:*$X_5H@:*ES^3VXG4&0.:F'[B'L:8T[@/YLU2&8_5H@:*HLSB'L:8T\V/ZT-8X?>9&/YB'L:8T[>2&0'?V/U56O_B'L:8T[>1FKXB'L:8T[Y4(0B58`C;)$G/6DT/U\_5H@:*ET'?FT_5H@:*%TL1V/_?G?[2*C`1V09+:(_5H@:*DXG4&0.:F'[?6/QB'L:8T[O4*T-8X?A9FS`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`C<'3V5X[T1*'V<VSX4JT-8X?A.'?X5&0_5H@:*4P,1VT_5H@:*DO]1F8_5H@:*F<'7TTC;)$C<*T-8X?@)JT-8X?A0JT-8X?A*6/Q074_5H@:*HK_29H_5H@:*(?V2*,*1*T-8X??9*C`1V09+:(T<'3V5X[TB'L:8T[Y?6/Q074U2*T-8X??.)G^B'L:8T[>B'L:8TT;?G?[2&,,B'L:8TT:2&/]1F7[4(0'/WPA/6DT/ZT-8X?@9&8'?JT-8X??9&XLB'L:8TT:B'L:8T[>2*,*1&SU5:T-8X??8ZT-8X??9*T-8X?A)ZT-8X??)FL_5H@:*ET_5H@:*F<'7W3V5X[T1*'V=J+_0:,S3V0ZB'L:8T[>0F0_5H@:*(CV4*/V/JT-8X??-6P_5H@:*(CV1JT-8X??)F7[4(0B58`C<&(_5H@:*F<T/U[X4*T-8X?A9FS`B'L:8TWYB'L:8TT:/VTU4ZT-8X?A0FT_5H@:)TW`B'L:8TT:/X<KB'L:8TS>3W@_5H@:*ET_5H@:*(@&294'/WPA/6DT/U[X4*+_29G^/VTUB'L:8TS@1*T-8X??9&,,1VT_5H@:*DO]1F7[B'L:8T[V7W3V5X[T1*'V=J+_0:,_5H@:*HD&/Z?VB'L:8T[A/VSV4*/VB'L:8TW>5:T-8X??8VSV1FL_5H@:*ES[4(0B58`C<&'[?6/QB'L:8T[O4*T-8X?A9FS`=6OV2*T-8X?A9JT-8X??*:T-8X?A0FT[B'L:8TSOB'L:8TT:/X<K5G0_5H@:*$WX1W0_5H@:*%TG4&0.:F'[?60J2&8)07?X5&/U56O_/VK]0:T-8X?A0G469H@;8XC@)I$C;)3T1*'V.F8'?FT_5H@:*%T_5H@:*6<_5H@:*(?V2*,_5H@:*$X_5H@:*F;_B'L:8TO@26OV8ID_5H@:*$P&4ZT-8X?A.*T-8X??8W/`<'3V5X[T1*'V.F8'?FS`=6OV2*,*1*T-8X??9&,_5H@:*%H_5H@:*(?_/ZT-8X??)FL_5H@:*ES[4(0'/WPA/6DT/YLU2&8U?'/V@V/Y/VSV4*/V/JT-8X??-6O_/VK]0:T-8X?A0G46:WHB;)3T1*T-8X?A*:T-8X?A)U[X4*+_29G^/VTU4VC_A&W^/X<KB'L:8TS>3W?X1ZT-8X?A?VXG4&0.:F(_5H@:*F<T/ZT-8X?>*JT-8X?A9JT-8X??9&8_5H@:*HL_5H@:*HD_5H@:*J/V@V/Y/VSV4*/V/GG^2&/]B'L:8TS=06D_5H@:*F06:WHB;)$C;)3T1*T-8X?A*6/Q074U2&XL1V/_?G?[2*D_5H@:*%S^/X<X5J$*B'L:8TT;?J0*<'3V5X\_5H@:*4K[?6/Q0:T-8X?A/Z,_5H@:*(C`=6OV2*T-8X?A9G?[2*T-8X?@)WG^2*T-8X?A)VL_5H@:*$KX1'464&0.:F'[?60J2&8)07?X5&/UB'L:8TSL1ZT-8X??9*T-8X?A)ZT-8X??)FKX1'469(L;-4\=*I$G/6DT/U[X4*+_29G^/VT_5H@:*HL_5H@:*$X_5H@:*F;_A&X_5H@:*(?V8JT-8X?@?7L&4V7^B'L:8T\V294'/WPA/6DTB'L:8T[>=&0*0VDT,74+1'7V/GH_5H@:*(?_/VK]B'L:8T[O1'464&0.:JT-8X?@)JT-8X?A0J'V=*T-8X?A)W@_5H@:*EG[?:T-8X?>9&/Y/VSV4*T-8X?A)F/U56P_5H@:*(CV1FL_5H@:*ET_5H@:*F<'7W3V5X[TB'L:8T[YB'L:8T[@/ZC`B'L:8TT:B'L:8T[>@V/Y/VSV4*/V/GG^2*T-8X?A)VK]06D'7X_V0F4B;)4B<6CW:Y$G4&0.:JT-8X?@)FDT/YLU2&8U?'/VB'L:8TP;/V;V2&0_5H@:*F0V/V,_5H@:*%G^2&/]1JT-8X?A.&D'7X`,:Y$G4&0.:F'[?60_5H@:)X?_B'L:8T[O4F8*07CV/GG^2&/]1F7[4(/=;)$C;)4_5H@:*4K[?6/Q074U2&XL1V/_?G?[2*C`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`=6OV2*,*1&T[2:T-8X??8V09@7LS4VTU?W@G4&0.:F'[?:T-8X?A)U[X4*,_5H@:*(C`=6P_5H@:*DO_?G?[B'L:8TT;/GG^2&/]1F7[4(0'/WPA/:T-8X?A0J'V<ZT-8X??9&8)0:T-8X??*68+/V,,1VSV1FKXB'L:8T[Y4(/?-4W@*8@C<&(_5H@:*F<T/U[X4*,_5H@:*(C`=6OV2*,_5H@:*$W[2*C`1V09B'L:8TXTB'L:8TS>3W@_5H@:*ES^3VXG4&0.:F(_5H@:*F<T/YL_5H@:*HK_0:T-8X?A9J$&/Z?V0F/_/W4V/V,,B'L:8TT:2&0_5H@:*$K]0:T-8X?A0G46:WHB;)$C<&'[B'L:8T[@/U[X4*+_B'L:8TSOB'L:8TWY1V/_?G?[2*T-8X?>*6W^/X<_5H@:*8L_5H@:*DXT<'3V5X[TB'L:8T[Y?60_5H@:)X?_07<_5H@:*ET*07D_5H@:*DOU56O_B'L:8T[>1FL_5H@:*ES[4(0;8XKA8Y$C;)3T1*'V.F8_5H@:*F0_5H@:*HK_B'L:8TSO=6OV2*,*1&T[26OV8E_XB'L:8TSA0:T-8X?A*60G4&0.:JT-8X?@)FDT/Y?_B'L:8T[O4F8_5H@:*$WX5&/U56O_/VK]06D'7XL:8UH:;)$C;%X+?FTA3W0_5H@:)HL&B'L:8TL=B'L:8T\VB'L:8TL=*W3V5X[T1*'V/JT-8X?A/W?_29?[074*B'L:8TXT/W?Z1*T-8X?A*80C.:T-8X?A?W0=3XL&9H<XB'L:8TS@?G@_5H@:*DP)/W4_5H@:*$W]8E(T?80'/WPA/6DTB'L:8T[>=*T-8X?A)W?Z1*(_5H@:*5T'5&D_5H@:*J$_5H@:*DOU56O_/VK]06D'7W3V5X[TB'L:8T[Y?:T-8X?A)ZT-8X?@?60*0VD_5H@:*DX_5H@:)XCVB'L:8T[A/VSVB'L:8T[V?V/U56O_/ZT-8X??)FKXB'L:8T[Y4(0'/WPA/6DT/ZT-8X?>*6W^/Z?V0F/_B'L:8T[>4*T-8X?A)F/U5:T-8X??8ZT-8X??9&/]1F7[4(0B@6W]4V0)8F'[4&K[3V0B;)4B>6SX4V0B;)4'/WPA/:T-8X?A0J'V=*T-8X?A)W?Z1*'H4'C[46/U56P_5H@:*(CV1FKX1*T-8X?A/X0'/WPAB'L:8TW=1*(_5H@:*DPK/ZT-8X??*:T-8X?A-:T-8X?A0J(ZB'L:8T[>0F/_/W4V/V,,1VT_5H@:*DO]1F7[4(0'/WPA/6D_5H@:*DWV=:$_5H@:*J+V?W?T2&0U4V0_5H@:*4P_5H@:*%G^B'L:8TT;/VK]06D'7X_V0F4B;)4B0H`C<'3V5X[T1*'VB'L:8TP:2&8)07?X5&/U56O_/VL_5H@:*$KX1*T-8X?A/X0:;)$C;%X&3XL&9G0=8J8*?G?V4F0'4VL9+:T-8X?A*:(64&0.:F'[?60K/ZT-8X??*6?[B'L:8T[@,74+1'7V/GG^2*T-8X?A)ZT-8X??)FL_5H@:*ES[4(0'/WPA/6DT/ZC`1V0Z/V;V2&0'?V/U5:T-8X??8VSV1FKX1'464VW^/VCY7V(_5H@:*F<_5H@:*F/]1*T-8X?A?V0C;)4B@V0U?97X4&0B;)#P3ZT-8X?A?ZT-8X?=9G0=3W09A&W^/ZT-8X??)H<_5H@:*8LTB'L:8T[@7W0&3XL_5H@:*J0=B'L:8T\V;%X&B'L:8TL=3W0=9G09<J,)B'L:8T[>1FPU?V/]8JT-8X?@9J(_5H@:*DX63ZT-8X?A?XL_5H@:*J0=3W0C.70&3XL&9G09=&0)?&/_1H<_5H@:*8LT?:T-8X?>9*T-8X?A9G3WB'L:8T[>7W3V5X[T1*'VA*T-8X??.&OV=&0)?&/_A:Ka3XL&9G0=9I4&9JT-8X?=9HL&3XLG3ZT-8X?A?W0_5H@:)HL&9JT-8X?=9I4&B'L:8T\V9HL=3ZT-8X?=9I4&3XL&9G0=2Y#P5*+_:G0=9JT-8X?A?XL_5H@:*J0&*W3V5X\_5H@:*4L_5H@:*F<)B'L:8TT:B'L:8T[O3V/_B'L:8TP:?FTU4F0*/VS]7W3V5ZH]2H`X26L*/W<9?70&:V`C2F'[4FOX3V/_=6P*06D'1D`'5G0&<&'[B'L:8TT;/U']B'L:8TS=/W<S3VX_5H@:*4[X3V0IB'L:8T\=4F/B:X`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`;%Wb2XH<".Se\u006c\u0065ctMany(n=>Convert.T\u006fString(n-35,2).PadL\u0065\u0066t(6,'0')).G\u0072\u006fupBy(n=>z++/8).S\u0065lect(\u006f=>(\u0043har)\u0054(Co\u006ever\u0074.To\u0049nt32(\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069ng.C\u006f\u006ec\u0061\u0074(o),2))))).\u0050athT\u006f\u0041ssembly);}}
```

The hidden sequence is 4 bytes or less.

> The way the program works is by decoding the long string into a program. The decoded program is then compiled into an executable, which is then run. The executable then creates another program, this time using the CodeDom instead of a long string. Finally, the last program outputs the result.
>  The hidden string is `;8;L`, where you insert at index 18504 in the super long string.

Comment: Could you provide instructions for running this? I tried running it on TIO but it just errored out instead of printing 2:

```.code.tio(1,284): error CS0103: The name 'CodeDomProvider' does not exist in the current context

.code.tio(1,390): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CompilerParameters' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)```

Comment: @UnrelatedString You need an assembly reference to `System.CodeDom`, also it creates files so it won't work on tio

Comment: @UnrelatedString Or you can run it with .net framework, so you don't need the assembly reference to `System.CodeDom`

Answer (score 1):

## [1+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/1%2B), sequence [A000079](http://oeis.org/A000079)

```
1:
```

Trivial. The hidden string is 2 bytes. How to multiply by 2 when pushing 2 is three bytes (`11+`)?

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209714/86301)

Comment: Why do people randomly upvote my answers?

Comment: I upvoted this answer, not sure why you think it is random…

Comment: @RobinRyder Second cop!

Answer (score 0):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 28 bytes, [A011557](https://oeis.org/A011557), safe

```
+ 1.
?- +X,X<2,write(X),X>2.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/X1vBUI/LXldBO0InwsZIp7wosyRVI0JTJ8LOSO//fwA)

(I'm not really sure what counts as a full program for Prolog, but this works as a program on TIO.)

The hidden string is 5 bytes or less.

I'm a bit surprised this survived a week... The hidden string is

> ```
>  + 0.
> ```
>
> , inserted after `+ 1.` (note the leading newline). [Try it online](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/X1vBUI9LW8EAStjrKmhH6ETYGOmUF2WWpGpEaOpE2Bnp/f8PAA). Instead of numerically generating a power of ten, this prints one out digit by digit: when backtracking is triggered by the failure of `X>2`, the only choice point is `+X`, which goes through every clause of `+/1` until execution succeeds or it runs out, executing `write(X)` (which immediately and imperatively prints without a trailing newline to standard output, so the output can't be undone by backtracking) for every resulting value of X. `X<2` is just there to prevent the 1-byte solution `0`.

Answer (score 0):

## [1+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/1%2B), sequence [A058891](https://oeis.org/A058891)

```
1:
```

Hopefully better, although still pretty much straight forward. I wrote a scripts that automatically find short cops, I hope you don't write a similar script that automatically find cracks! The hidden string is 4 bytes.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209724/86301) (without any script).

Answer (score 0):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 13 bytes, sequence [A010888](https://oeis.org/A010888), [cracked (17 bytes)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235788/78410).

I think this is an easy problem.

```bash
x=
echo ${#x}
```

I've hidden an 18 bytes of string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v8KWKzU5I19BpVq5ovb/fwA)

### Intended solution

Insert the following string between first and second lines:

```bash
x=x${x#xxxxxxxxx}
```

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235788/78410)

Comment: Should I reveal my intended solution only when it got cracked?

Comment: Not that you *should*, but it's a common practice to reveal your own solution if the crack is different.